# Pseudoeffective line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $L$ be a pseudoeffective line bundle on a complex manifold $X$ then is there a singular hermitian metric of $L$ which its curvature is not semi-positive?

Comment: Well, yes, even if $L$ is ample one can take some K\"ahler metric $\omega$ and subtract some large multiple of $dd^c\phi$ for some $\phi$. If you choose a decent $\phi$ this will no longer be semi-positive.

Comment: @Jarek: When you say "not semipositive", do you mean "nowhere semipositive"? Then the trivial bundle on the projective line is pseudoeffective, but any connection on it has semipositive curvature somewhere: no, trivially. On the other hand, if you mean "not semipositive at some point", then Ruadhai's comment applies: yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a singular Hermitian metric on $L$ whose curvature *is* semipositive. See Demailly, *[On the cohomology of pseudoeffective line bundles](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5432v1)*, for a very clear survey.